# jQuery roundabout momentum scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know about how I would implement roundabout style scrolling for touch screen devices via jQuery or JavaScript, so if I scroll/drag the roundabout would spin as I scroll?

Can someone hook up an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the point where the "swipe" starts then track it's motion to determine what to do:

```
$(document).on('vmousedown', function (event) {

    //the swipe has started, get the starting point saved for later
    $.data(this, 'swipe-start', { x : event.pageX, y : event.pageY });
}).on('vmouseup', function (event) {

    //set the swipe-start date to null to we can start anew,
    //this allows you to fire more than one control event with a single swipe,
    //so long swipes trigger more control events than short ones
    $.data(this, 'swipe-start', null);
}).on('vmousemove', function (event) {
    if ($.data(this, 'swipe-start') != null) {
        //here we can see how far the swipe has gone and in what direction
        var distanceX = $.data(this, 'swipe-start').x - event.pageX,
            distanceY = $.data(this, 'swipe-start').y - event.pageY,
            distanceT = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs($.data(this, 'swipe-start').x - event.pageX), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs($.data(this, 'swipe-start').y - event.pageY), 2));
    
        //let the user swipe at least 50 pixels before deciding what to do
        if (distanceT > 50) {
            if (distanceX > 0 && distanceY > 0) {
                //user went up and to the right
                $('.ui-content').append('<p>You went up/left</p>');
            } else if (distanceX < 0 && distanceY > 0) {
                //user went up and to the left
                $('.ui-content').append('<p>You went up/right</p>');
            } else if (distanceX < 0 && distanceY < 0) {
                //user went down and to the left
                $('.ui-content').append('<p>You went down/right</p>');
            } else {
                //user went down and to the right
                $('.ui-content').append('<p>You went down/left</p>');
            }
            //reset the 'swipe-start' incase the user keeps swiping
            $.data(this, 'swipe-start', { x : event.pageX, y : event.pageY });
        }
    }
});​
```

Then inside the proper `if/then` statement you place the code that controls your UI element.

Note that `vmousedown`/`vmouseup`/`vmousemove` are jQuery Mobile custom events meant to function for mouse and touch input.

## update

I updated the above code a bit to be more user-friendly, also there were a couple issues I had to work-out. Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sRxFC/1/

Note that if you want to involve momentum you will also need to track the speed of the swipe to determine velocity rather than just direction.

Comment: Thanks! Im trying to move a graphic in real time as the user is swiping, I guess a slight modification would let me do that

Comment: Yeah, just change to the minimum distance to something really low.

Answer (score 0):

if do you want custom scrollpaths then [this jQuery plugin](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) might help you... if you "just" want to show a roundabout while scrolling then I would suggest to observe the scroll event via JS and do some transitions via CSS

or did I completely misunderstood you?

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question (which wanted to add scroll momentum), but what a great link. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying out the jQuery plugin Roundabout. If you want something that's close to out the box and it just works I'd highly recommend the plugin and it's ability to support drag/swipe via the enableDrag property.  I've only tested so far on iOS devices but it works well there and I imagine it would work on other touch platforms.

[Roundabout Project Page](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout) and
[How to enable Drag/Swipe](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout#/enableDrag)